# How to extract equation between brackets Python 2.7?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to extract an equation between brackets but i don't know how to do it in python 2.7.

i tried `re.findall` but i think the pattern is wrong.

```
child = {(x1<25)*2 +((x1>=25)&&(x2<200))*2+((x1>=25)&&(x2>=200))*1}

stringExtract = re.findall(r'\{(?:[^()]*|\([^()]*\))*\}', child)
```

it returns nothing instead of `x1<25)*2 +((x1>=25)&&(x2<200))*2+((x1>=25)&&(x2>=200))*1`

Comment: `child` doesn't seem a string, and `re.findall` should be used on string. The given exemple is not even compiling for me, can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: `child.lstrip('{').rstrip('}')`, given child is a string which is `child = '{(x1<25)*2 +((x1>=25)&&(x2<200))*2+((x1>=25)&&(x2>=200))*1}'`

Comment: If you mean `child = '{(x1<25)*2 +((x1>=25)&&(x2<200))*2+((x1>=25)&&(x2>=200))*1}'` then `child[1:-1]` should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're only interested in everything between `{` and `}`, so your regex could be much simpler:

```
import re
child = "{(x1<25)*2 +((x1>=25)&&(x2<200))*2+((x1>=25)&&(x2>=200))*1}"    
pattern = re.compile("""
    \s*     # every whitespace before leading bracket
    {(.*)}  # everything between '{' and '}'
    \s*     # every whitespace after ending bracket
""", re.VERBOSE)
re.findall(pattern, child)
```

And the output is this:

```
['(x1<25)*2 +((x1>=25)&&(x2<200))*2+((x1>=25)&&(x2>=200))*1']
```

To get the string from the list (`re.findall()` returns a `list`), you can access it via index position zero: `re.findall(pattern, child)[0]`. But also the other methods for `re` could be interesting for you, i.e. [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) or [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match).

But if every string has a leading bracket and an ending bracket at first and last position, you can also simply do this:

```
child[1:-1]
```

which gives you

```
'(x1<25)*2 +((x1>=25)&&(x2<200))*2+((x1>=25)&&(x2>=200))*1'
```

Comment: The pattern could be simplified for `re.findall()` to this: `pattern = re.compile("{(.*)}")`. With the whitespaces the regex it's also portable for `re.match()` (if there are any potential whitespaces, of course).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex - `{([^}]*)}`. It matches the character `{` then `[^}]*` matches anything except `}` and `}` matches the end bracket.

```
>>> import re
>>> eq = "{(x1<25)*2 +((x1>=25)&&(x2<200))*2+((x1>=25)&&(x2>=200))*1}"
>>> m = re.search("{([^}]*)}", eq)
>>> m.group(1)
'(x1<25)*2 +((x1>=25)&&(x2<200))*2+((x1>=25)&&(x2>=200))*1'
```